# How to create a collage preview of images like FaceBook?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement image collage preview like Facebook while posting images, [image: as shown in image]

so far i have created 5 layouts according to multiple image count and then i am inflating the layouts according to selected image list and setting image in forloop, i also need to show document icon if any selected.

Here is the code which i have implemented.

```
private void displayCollage() {
    rlLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    rlLayout.removeAllViews();
    imagelayout5Binding.tvCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (attachList.size() > 0) {
        int count = attachList.size();
        if (count > 5) {
            count = 6;
        }

        switch (count) {
            case 1:
                DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout1Binding.ivImage, 0);
                rlLayout.addView(imagelayout1Binding.getRoot());
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i <= attachList.size(); i++) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout2Binding.ivImage1, i);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout2Binding.ivImage2, i);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                rlLayout.addView(imagelayout2Binding.getRoot());
                break;
            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i <= attachList.size(); i++) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout3Binding.ivImage1, i);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout3Binding.ivImage2, i);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout3Binding.ivImage3, i);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                rlLayout.addView(imagelayout3Binding.getRoot());
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int i = 0; i <= attachList.size(); i++) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout4Binding.ivImage1, i);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout4Binding.ivImage2, i);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout4Binding.ivImage3, i);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout4Binding.ivImage4, i);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                rlLayout.addView(imagelayout4Binding.getRoot());
                break;
            case 5:
                for (int i = 0; i <= attachList.size(); i++) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage1, i);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage2, i);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage3, i);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage4, i);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage5, i);
                            break;
                    }

                }
                rlLayout.addView(imagelayout5Binding.getRoot());
                break;
            case 6:
                for (int i = 0; i <= attachList.size(); i++) {
                    if (i >= attachList.size()) {
                        i = 5;
                    }
                    switch (i) {
                        case 0:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage1, i);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage2, i);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage3, i);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage4, i);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.ivImage5, i);
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            DisplayCollageImage(imagelayout5Binding.tvCount);
                            break;
                    }

                    if (i == 5) {
                        break;
                    }

                }
                rlLayout.addView(imagelayout5Binding.getRoot());
                break;
        }

    } else {
        rlLayout.removeAllViews();
    }

}
```

but doing this is taking too much processing time, please help me how can i reduce this processing time.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: ok what changes do i have to make in question

Comment: Not ask us to suggest anything?

Comment: @AKSHAYMANAGOOLI best option **[FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)**

Comment: I will try @NileshRathod

Comment: @NileshRathod yes flexbox would work but i want to disable scroll. it should show only 5 images and then at last image +5 etc..

Comment: @NileshRathod flexbox not helping

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve the above output then i would suggest using a Recyclerview with StaggeredGrid Layout

Comment: yes i tried but, i need to set it fixed, if i use recyclerview with staggeredgrid layout, then it will allow to scroll,

Comment: see if this helps https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4796 https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2402

Comment: No staggeredgrid layout not helping

Comment: Did you check the library links i pasted above ? in the reply

Comment: oh sorry i will check them'

Comment: yes i have checked these links , but non of them works for me